# How can I get the name of the all snapshot of RDS DB instance created manually using the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

How can I get the name of the all snapshot of RDS DB instance created manually  using the AWS CLI?

I am using below command

```
aws rds describe-db-cluster-snapshots \
--query "sort_by(DBSnapshotIdentifier, &SnapshotCreateTime)"
```

and It is giving me error

> In function sort_by(), invalid type for value: None, expected one of: ['array'], received: "null"

Comment: Typo: DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier or DBClusterIdentifier?

Answer (score 0):

The command you are using is for DB clusters not instances, instead you will need to use

> describe-db-snapshots

Example usage as follows:

> $ aws rds describe-db-snapshots --db-instance-identifier
> [rds-instance-arn] --region [aws-region]

**aws-region:** can be like: eu-central-1 or whatever region you are using

**rds-instance-arn:** can be found in AWS console or you can get it from the output of this command:

> $ aws rds describe-db-instances --region [aws-region]